# Работа с SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-shared-preferences

Не могу разобраться, почему не создается файл в папке пакета приложения с данными, которые я передаю.

Вот код:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    private TextInputLayout mUsernameLayout, currentIpLayout, prefLayout;
    private EditText mUsername, currentIp, pref;
    private Button changeIp, saveSettings;
    private View view;
    private SharedPreferences mSettings;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);
        mSettings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(BasicSettings.APP_Preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        mUsernameLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.username_layout);
        currentIpLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ipdb_layout);
        prefLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pref_layout);

        currentIp = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_ipCDB);
        mUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_username);
        pref  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_pref);

        changeIp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.changeIp);
        saveSettings = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.saveSettings);

        changeIp.setOnClickListener(this);
        saveSettings.setOnClickListener(this);

        if(mSettings.contains(BasicSettings.APP_Preferences)){
            mUsername.setText(mSettings.getString(BasicSettings.APP_Preferences_UserName, ""));
            currentIp.setText(mSettings.getString(BasicSettings.APP_Preferences_IPDB, BasicSettings.RemoteDB_Adress));
            pref.setText(mSettings.getString (BasicSettings.APP_Preferences_Pref, ""));
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.saveSettings:
                onClickSaveSettings();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void onClickSaveSettings(){           
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
            editor.putString(BasicSettings.APP_Preferences_UserName, mUsername.getText().toString());
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Данные были успешно сохранены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что сообщений об ошибках нет, но файл с данными не появляется, как следствие они не считываются. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: А вы уверены, что метод `onClick....` запускается?

Comment: @rjhdby, да, т.к. отрабатывает тост

Comment: @rjhdby, и отладчиком проверял

Comment: Метод `contains` проверяет наличие ключа, а не файла. А ключа с именем `BasicSettings.APP_Preferences` у вас скорее всего нет. Попробуйте `if(mSettings.contains(BasicSettings.APP_Preferences_UserName))`

Comment: @eugeneek, вы правы, заработало) спасибо огромное. Сделаете в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его отметить как правильный?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `contains` проверяет наличие ключа, а не файла. А ключа с именем `BasicSettings.APP_Preferences` у вас скорее всего нет.

Попробуйте так:

```
if(mSettings.contains(BasicSettings.APP_Preferences_UserName‌​)){
    ...
}
```